# Trying to get my .click(function()) to run x-amount of times

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I’m using a select menu with numbered options from 1–6. When someone selects option 3, I want my `.click(function(){})` to run 3 times, or if someone selects 5 then my `.click(function(){})` would run 5 times. I was thinking about adding an `onchange` to my input select. Does anyone have suggestions about how I should set this up?

Here are the basics of my code:

```js
//biscuit
var idCounter = 1;

$("#addbiscuit").click(function() {

  var val = $("#txtAdd").val();
  var imageElement = $("<div class='sample_holder'><div class='biscuit'>.  <input type='image' src='Images/Merge Samples/Samplebox/102Biscuit.png' width='70%' name='closeStory' class='close_bisq_btn' width='22px'><p style='font-size: 9px';>click to remove</p><div class='checkbox'><label for='biscuit" + idCounter + "'>" + val + "</label><input id='biscuit" + idCounter + "' type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='#120 Biscuit monochrome'" + val + "' checked /></div></div></div>");
  idCounter++;
  if (maxAppend > 0) {
    $("#samplebox").append(imageElement);
    maxAppend--;
    $('#Grid input[type=checkbox]').attr('checked', 'checked');
  }

});

$("#samplebox").on('click', '.close_bisq_btn', function() {
  $(this).closest('.biscuit').remove();
  maxAppend++;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="howManyBiscuits" name="howManyBiscuits" onchange="">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
</select>

<button id="addbiscuit" class="AddButton">Add This Sample To My Tray</button>
```

Comment: you can consider using jquery trigger functions

Comment: Have you tried a for loop in the click event which runs against the value of the item?

Comment: So for example: for(var i = 0; i < this.value; i++){ and in here the function }

Comment: You'll only get one click event per click, so you won't get the handler to run multiple times out of the box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is a bit confusing and there was missing code. Were you looking to add new elements based on the number of biscuits selected? See the demo below and let me know.

```js
$("#addbiscuit").click(function() {
  var bisciutCount = $( "select#howManyBiscuits option:checked" ).val();
  var val = $("#txtAdd").val();
  for (var i = 1; i <= bisciutCount; i++){
  var imageElement = $("<div class='sample_holder'><div class='biscuit'>  <input type='image' src='http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-OQ_wj5FWmqY/UC-TYphU4pI/AAAAAAAAAds/jUe8AnHTiSo/s1600/50x50.gif' width='10%' name='closeStory' class='close_bisq_btn' width='22px'><p style='font-size: 9px';>click to remove</p><div class='checkbox'><label for='biscuit" + i + "'>" + "Biscuit ID: " + i + "</label><input id='biscuit" + i + "' type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='#120 Biscuit monochrome'" + val + "' checked /></div></div></div>");
    $("#samplebox").append(imageElement);
    $('#Grid input[type=checkbox]').attr('checked', 'checked');
}
});

$("#samplebox").on('click', '.close_bisq_btn', function() {
  $(this).closest('.sample_holder').remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="howManyBiscuits" name="howManyBiscuits" onchange="">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
</select>

<button id="addbiscuit" class="AddButton">Add This Sample To My Tray</button>

<div id="samplebox">

</div>
```

Comment: Yes, based on your code snippet, I believe you understood exactly what I was looking for! Sorry for the confusion, I was having a hard time wording my question. I'm not super strong in java script

Comment: Glad to help. If this answered your question, consider upvoting/marking it as the correct answer. Thanks.

Comment: So you code works! However, I need to limit the total amount of appended elements to 12, meaning there can not be more than 12 elements in the sample box. Could you help me do that? I had code that did it before, but I cannot get it to work with the changes you made. Is there a place I could show you more of my original coding?

Comment: Just change the for loop by adding another condition: `for (var i = 1; i <= bisciutCount && i <= 12; i++){...}`

Comment: hmm, I updated the loop and it didn't seem to work. Also, in my code I have several functions just like the $("#addbiscuit").click(function() (they all add to the sample box). I need a universal limit of 12 if that makes sense. I believe the for loop update you gave me would just limit the amount of "biscuits" added to the box, which is still very helpful. Would you be able to show me how to set a universal limit? I had something like:                       var maxAppend= 12; var idCounter= 1; and each time a "biscuit" was added:  (look at my next comment)

Comment: idCounter ++; 
     if (maxAppend > 0) {
          $("#samplebox").append(imageElement);
          maxAppend--; 
        $('#Grid input[type=checkbox]').attr('checked','checked');
     }
  });

Comment: Busy weekend... Instead of `&& i <= 12`, use '&& idCounter <= maxAppend`. Then add you line setting the maxAppend above of the loop and `idCounter++` inside of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is isolate the functionality that you want to repeat. Then put that functionality inside a function. A function bound to your click event will trigger the repetition. The value of your howManyBiscuits field will dictate how many times the loop is repeated.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function clickHandler(value) {
    $(results).append("<p>Item" + value + "</p>");
  }

  $("#addbiscuit").on('click', function() {
    var repeatVal = $("select[name=howManyBiscuits]").val();
    $(results).html("");
    for (var i = 0; i < repeatVal; i++) {
      clickHandler(i + 1);
    }

  });


});
```

```html
<select id="howManyBiscuits" name="howManyBiscuits" onchange="">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
</select>

<button id="addbiscuit" class="AddButton">Add This Sample To My Tray</button>

<id id="results"></id>
```